# Approximately when is the story of "Boku no Hero Academia" set?

Tags: my-hero-academia

As nearly as I can tell, the events of "Boku no Hero Academia" seem to begin some time around 2174.  I base this estimation upon the manga having been begun in 2014 and the current All Might being the 8th such hero (and taking an assumed average of 20 years per generation between passings-on of their power).

Is there a definitive answer for this?  If not, are there canon facts, observed trends, or even fan-based assumptions that might at least weigh to the contrary (whether earlier or later than 2174)?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a defnitive answer. But in regard of fan theories, Google came up with [this](https://www.quora.com/What-year-does-Boku-no-Hero-Academia-take-place-What-are-your-theories) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/BokuNoHeroAcademia/comments/4qww6o/just_how_much_time_has_passed_in_the_world_of_bnha/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's around the years 2060 and 2085. Deku's hero license says 20XX on it, so it can't be past 2099.

1st gen All Might is around 1950. Also, tech has progressed because of quirks.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references to support your answer.

Comment: @Cak3 I believe that your point is valid: upon Googling "Deku's hero license" I found some fairly clear copies, and it does list an issuance date of "交付 20XX".

Answer (score 2):

Unless canon ever gives us an exact year, it’s impossible to say for sure. Thematically though, the story takes place [20 minutes into the future](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TwentyMinutesIntoTheFuture).

Technology and culture is almost identical to today, *except* that there are people with superpowers and this has been for generations. The problems that the character’s face, and society as a whole face, aren’t that different from the problems we face in real life (except dialed up to 11 because of the presence of Quirks, and the fact that this is an action work of fiction).

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking around on different sites to get a clearer answer on this, but the most I can tell is that at least the current timeline of Deku at UA takes place in the 21st century since his ID apparently reads 20XX. This is common in a lot of anime/manga from my experience, but if we take that as an actual indicator, then the latest it could possibly take place is 2099.

Now, if you want to start mixing fandoms, I do recall that the manga makes reference to Marvel characters, and if we mix the MCU into things, then MHA would be taking place not too far from our own timeline.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's the year that the glowing baby was born. There's no way of knowing what year it was, but since technology isn't that much more advanced than ours, and we're told it was halted by the appearance of quirks, we can safely assume that it was in the early-to-mid 21st century. Then there's the fact that we see snow in Japan, a near-equator country getting hit by warmer winds from the ocean. Since dealing with quirks tore the world's focus away from other issues such as climate change, I think we should definitely assume that the world had time to deal with humanity's massive carbon footprint, something that, given our current situation, would likely take twenty or so years to properly deal with. Yes, I know there's the horribly trashed beach that All Might had Izuku clean up, but litter and greenhouse gases are two different things, and given the current real-life situation, I think it's safe to say which one the world prioritized. Besides, a lot of that could easily have been floating in the ocean for decades. All in all, I think the glowing baby was born around 2050.

Then there's the initial backlash and the appearance of All for One. It likely took the world between five and ten years to fully react to the initial appearance of quirks, and All for One appeared pretty early on, so we'll say that All for One appeared about ten years after the glowing baby, around 2060.

Now for how long the quirk society has been around. The doctor specifically states that Izuku is a part of the fourth generation. In the developed world, parents tend to have kids near middle age, so I think it can be safely assumed that each generation is around thirty to forty years (we'll round it at thirty-five on average). If Izuku was born early in his generation, we can probably say that he was born around 110 years after the fiasco with All for One and his brother, putting us at around 2170 when he was born. This checks out with All for One having been in power for over a hundred years.

Now, one reason you may think it doesn't check out is the fact that Izuku is the ninth holder of One for All, something we previously said appeared around 2060. There are those who draw a pattern from the fact that Toshinori and Izuku both received One for All at the age of fifteen, and saying this probably went for everyone. However, they are special cases due to them both being quirkless kids in a superpowered society that wanted to go to a high school for heroes - something that kind of required a quirk. Most of the bearers were likely adults when they received it, due to experience as a hero and with the quirk they already had being a good mix with something so powerful. They likely received it at a later age, shortening the time they had to use it. Most notably, All for One's brother probably didn't hold on to it for very long, as he knew early on that he would need to pass the quirk on to future generations. With All Might having probably had the quirk for around fifteen years before Izuku was born, and the first user probably holding it on for ten to fifteen years, this puts the average time of holding the quirk at fifteen years for the others, though some may have passed it on prematurely due to injuries or expecting to do something that would get them killed, so I think it's safe to assume that, in this timeframe, the median retention time of One for All was around twenty or so years.

So with all of that, in addition to Izuku being fourteen at the beginning, fifteen at the current point in the anime, and sixteen at the current point in the manga, I believe that *My Hero Academia* takes place right around the turn of the 23rd century.

Comment: Japan's not terribly near to the equator (it's ~31° N through ~45° N latitude), and snow is reasonably normal there (I spent 4 years in Tokyo), but the rest of your reasoning is sound.  Your resulting 2170 is much like my estimated 2174, which reassures my own guesses, since you took a different route to arrive at that (I particularly like the observation about All For One's reign being >100 years).

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the time, if Endeavor was born in 1989, it would be 2035 since he's 46 in the current My Hero universe. But considering this is also in the past and it's the story being told by Deku, it might be 2048 and by the end, it would be 2134.

Answer (score 0):

It takes place in our century but in a different universe where 80% of people have powers. I said our century because the technology is the same as ours and the different universe because of the power.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's set into a decent future.

From what I've seen (which is mid-season 2), I'm not totally sure and I came here to find this out, but I actually don't think it is just 20 minutes into the future as [Mr F.'s answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/48157/2516) mentioned.

I mainly came here because of a quote stating that it is predicted that humans would've been a lot more advanced if not for the development of quirks slowing everything down and how we would have been expected to have had space cruises by now, so I expect it's around the year 2100.